# Should PhD student always co-author its advisor

Tags: citations, advisor

Is it a must for a PhD student to co-author its advisor? What about if the student writes a paper by itself? What about collaborating with friends?

Comment: Your advising relationship has absolutely nothing to do with whether or not you must cite someone else's work.

Comment: @JeffE, I meant to give them a co-authorship. Sorry

Comment: "What about if the student writes a paper by itself?": if a student is capable of writing a (decent) paper all by themselves, well, that's good and let's celebrate the publication! What else?

Comment: Your advising relationship has absolutely nothing to do with whether or not someone should be a coauthor.